# Problem with infinite product using iterating of a function: $ \exp(x) = x \cdot f^{\circ 1}(x)\cdot f^{\circ 2}(x) \cdot \ldots $

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, functional-analysis

*[update]: I made the question more precise, more general and added a follow up question*

Considering the iteration of functions (with focus on the iterated exponentiation) I'm looking, whether some function which I want to iterate can -hopefully with some advantage- itself be expressed by iterations of a -so to say- "more basic" function.

Fo example I assume a function $f(x)$ such that

$ \qquad \displaystyle \exp(x) =  x \cdot f^{\circ 1}(x)\cdot f^{\circ 2}(x)\cdot f^{\circ 3}(x)\cdots   $
$\qquad \qquad$ *(where the circle-notation means iteration, and $f^{\circ 0}=x, f^{\circ 1}(x)=f(x)$)*

and first I ask: what does this function $f(x)$ look like?

What I'm doing is this substitution:
$$ \small \begin{array} {lrll}
1.& \exp(x) & = &x & \cdot f^{\circ 1}(x) & \cdot f^{\circ 2}(x) & \cdot f^{\circ 3}(x) & \cdots  \\
2.& \exp(f(x))&= && f^{\circ 1}(x) & \cdot f^{\circ 2}(x) & \cdot f^{\circ 3}(x) & \cdots  \\   \\  \\
3.& {\exp(f(x))\over \exp(x) } & = & \frac 1x \\ \\
& \exp(f(x)) & = & &{ \exp(x) \over x} \\ \\ \\ 
4. & f(x)&=& x & - \log(x) \end{array} $$
$ \qquad \qquad $ *(From 1. and 4. I know, that x is now restricted to $x \gt 0$)*

As some comments point out, the construction of the function $f(x)$ is underdetermined; so in step $3.$ numerator and denominator can have a common factor $c$ such that we'll have
$$ \small \begin{array} {lrll}
1a.& \exp(x)\cdot c & = &x & \cdot f^{\circ 1}(x) & \cdot f^{\circ 2}(x) & \cdot f^{\circ 3}(x) & \cdots  \\
2a.& \exp(f(x)) \cdot c&= && f^{\circ 1}(x) & \cdot f^{\circ 2}(x) & \cdot f^{\circ 3}(x) & \cdots   \end{array} $$

If I do now the computation with some example $x$ by 
$$ y =  x \cdot f^{\circ 1}(x)\cdot f^{\circ 2}(x)\cdot f^{\circ 3}(x)\cdots $$
I get for all tested $x>0$ the result
$$ y = \exp(x) / \exp(1)  $$
such that indeed a cofactor $c$ occurs and that it is precisely $1 / \exp(1)$

***Q1:*** Where does this additional factor in the empirical evaluation come from? Where have the above analytical steps missed some crucial information?

The question can made more precise:
***Q2:*** How does the empiricial computation determine, that the cofactor $c$ is just $1/\exp(1)$ ?

*(The comments of @Eric Wong adress this questions, but I've not yet made it explicite)*

---

In reviewing my own question, a generalization is possible in that I can use any base $b$ with $\log(b)\ge 1$ such that

$ \qquad \displaystyle {b^x \over b} =  x \cdot f_b^{\circ 1}(x)\cdot f_b^{\circ 2}(x)\cdot f_b^{\circ 3}(x)\cdots   $

and the constant $c$ comes always out to equal $1/b$ such that we might as well  write
$ \qquad \displaystyle b^{x-1} =  x \cdot f_b^{\circ 1}(x)\cdot f_b^{\circ 2}(x)\cdot f_b^{\circ 3}(x)\cdots   $

***Q3:*** Can Eric's comment made be more explicite such that it shall work for all that bases?

---

I observe, that for $\eta < \log(b) <1$ with $\eta \lt 0.39996 $ the sequence of iterates of the functions $f_b(x)$ either approach $1$ alternating from below and above or don't approach $1$ at all but approach distinct accumulation-points... *That observation is important here, because for such bases $b$ the above productformula does not work correctly, because we get sometimes no convergence to a single fixpoint. But due to the remark of @did I moved that question into a [separate thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445651/iterates-of-f-bx-x-log-bx-for-logb-approx-0-399-convergence)*

---

A code snippet using Pari/GP:

```
f(x) = x-log(x)  \\ define the function 

x0=1.5
     \\  = 1.50000000000
[tmp=x0,pr=1]              \\ initialize
for(k=1,64,pr *= tmp;tmp = f(tmp));   pr   \\ compute 64 terms, show result
      \\ = 1.64872127070

exp(x0)        \\ show expected value
       \\ = 4.48168907034

pr*exp(1)      \\ show, how it matches
       \\  = 4.48168907034
```

---

Here is an example which shows the type of convergence; I use $x_0=1.5$ and internal precision of 200 decimal digits. Then we get the terms of the partial product as
$$ \small \begin{array} {r|r}
 x_k=f^{\circ k}(x) & (x_k-1) \\
 \hline
 1.50000000000 & 0.500000000000 \\
 1.09453489189 & 0.0945348918918 \\
 1.00420537512 & 0.00420537512103 \\
 1.00000881788 & 0.00000881787694501 \\
 1.00000000004 & 3.88772483656E-11 \\
 1.00000000000 & 7.55720220223E-22 \\
 1.00000000000 & 2.85556525627E-43 \\
 1.00000000000 & 4.07712646640E-86 \\
 1.00000000000 & 8.31148011150E-172 \\
 1.00000000000 & 1.020640763E-202 \\
 1.00000000000 & 1.020640763E-202 \\
  \cdots  &  \cdots
 \end{array}
$$

Comment: I don't follow how you got $y=\exp(x)/\exp(1)$. If all you do is substitute $y=\exp(x)$ in the above calculation of course you should arrive at the same conclusion. Could you elaborate on how you arrived at this result?

Comment: @nullUser: eqn. 2 comes from eqn. 1 just by inserting $f^{\circ  1}(x)$ instead of $x$, which is simply $f^{\circ  0}(x)$. Then all the infinite product "shifts" one position to the right

Comment: I understand that part. I follow the calculations all the way through $f(x)=x-\log(x)$. But then you claim that if $y = x f \cdots$ then $y=\exp(x)/\exp(1)$ which does not follow from any of the previousq calculations.

Comment: I'd also like to see this derived, but I wouldn't call it an extra factor.  Notice that your calculation to deduce $f(x)$ goes through exactly the same for $\exp(x) = C\cdot x \cdot f(x) \cdot f(f(x)) \cdots$.  In other words, the original assumption overdetermines $f(x)$.

Comment: ;-) yes, that doesn't follow. But it occurs, if I actually do the computation with some example value x, say x=1.5. Then the infinite product, let's call it "p" gives $ p = 1.64872127070$ but $\exp(1.5) = 4.48168907034$ which is just $ p\cdot \exp(1)=4.48168907034 $ That's just my question

Comment: @Erick: Yes, I've also seen, that a constant factor in 1. and in 2. would explain the result. But how would it occur there? And why would it be just $\exp(1)$? Btw, the ratio  $\exp(1.5)/pr$ was 2.718... with the known digits to several places corect so it is easy to assume it is just $\exp(1)$

Comment: @GottfriedHelms In order for the product to converge non-trivially the terms must tend to $1$.  If $f$ is assumed to be nice then it should have $1$ as a fixed point.  This makes it impossible for the RHS to be $\exp(x)$ when $x=1$, but it sure might be $\exp(x)/\exp(1)$.  The real question seems to be why does the iteration (empirically) converge?

Comment: To answer my own question, I suppose it converges simply because when $x = 1+\epsilon$, $x - \ln x \approx 1 + \tfrac12\epsilon^2$, so the product is very rapidly convergent once the terms approach $1$.

Comment: There seems to be three questions here: Q1-Q2, essentially solved in the comments four months ago (except that I would call the function f overdetermined, not underdetermined), Q3, to which the analysis used to solve Q1-Q2 can be easily generalized, and finally Q4, entirely different. Conflating these in a same post, already long and somewhat difficult to follow, is definitely a bad idea.

Comment: @Did: hmm, true... perhaps I should ask Q4 as a separate question with less context.... Also I'm getting more used to Eric's argument, which I understood only as a (more qualitative) answer *that* it can converge to a fixpoint and did not see, that the answer for "why does it empirically to *such a value*?" might also be included - which I begin to get a grip of now...

Comment: See my post for a recapitulating answer to Q1-Q2-Q3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say that $f$ solves $(\ast)$ for $g$ if $g(x)=x\cdot f(x)\cdot f\circ f(x)\cdot f\circ f\circ f(x)\cdots$, in the sense that the product in the RHS converges and that its value is $g(x)$, for every positive $x$.

The computations in the post and in some comments show that, if $f$ solves $(\ast)$ for $g:x\mapsto c\mathrm e^x$ for some positive $c$ then $f:x\mapsto x-\log x$, and that $f:x\mapsto x-\log x$ indeed solves $(\ast)$ for $g:x\mapsto\mathrm e^{x-1}$ and not for any other $g:x\mapsto c\mathrm e^x$.

More generally, note that if $f$ solves $(\ast)$ for $g$ then $g(f(x))=f(x)\cdot f\circ f(x)\cdot f\circ f\circ f(x)\cdots$ hence 
$$
x\cdot g(f(x))=g(x).
$$
Assuming that $g$ is invertible, for example because $g$ is increasing, we consider the function $Tg$ defined by
$$
Tg(x)=g^{-1}(g(x)/x).
$$
Then the only possible solution of $(\ast)$ is $f=Tg$, in particular $f$ is unique and such that $f(1)=1$ when it exists. Thus, for $(\ast)$ to have solutions, one must assume that $g(1)=1$.

Assume furthermore that $g'(1)$ exists, thus, $g(1+\varepsilon)=1+g'(1)\varepsilon+o(\varepsilon)$ when $\varepsilon\to0$. Then $Tg(1+\varepsilon)=1+\eta$ with $g'(1)\eta+o(\eta)=(g'(1)-1)\varepsilon+o(\varepsilon)$. If $g'(1)\lt1/2$, the point $1$ is repulsive for $f$ hence the product in the RHS of $(\ast)$ diverges and $(\ast)$ has no solution. If $g'(1)\gt1/2$, the ratio $(g'(1)-1)/g'(1)$ is in $(-1,1)$ hence the infinite product converges and $(\ast)$ has the unique solution $Tg$.

In the specific case when $g(x)=\mathrm e^{x-1}$, then $g'(1)=1$ hence $(\ast)$ has a unique solution $f=Tg$ and one knows that $Tg:x\mapsto x-\log x$.

In the specific case when $g(x)=b^{x-1}$ for some positive $b$, then $g'(1)=\log b$ hence $(\ast)$ has a unique solution $f=Tg$ when $b\gt\sqrt{\mathrm e}$ and one knows that $Tg:x\mapsto x-\log_b x$, and $(\ast)$ has no solution when $b\lt\sqrt{\mathrm e}$.

In the limit regime $b=\sqrt{e}$, a more careful analysis of the sequences $(x_n)$ defined by $1+x_{n+1}=Tg(1+x_n)$ shows that $(x_n)$ is ultimately alternated (decreasing in modulus and alternatively positive and negative for every $n$ large enough), thus the infinite product $\prod\limits_n(1+x_n)$ converges and $(\ast)$ has a unique solution $f=Tg:x\mapsto x-2\log x$ in this case too.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! Especially for the arguments about the bases $1 \lt b \lt \sqrt e$ and $\sqrt e \le b \le e$ at which I'll look deeper in the afternoon. *(replacing old comment because of funny typos ...)*

Answer (score 1):

The constant c from (1a) is canceled out in step (3).
The constant c must be calculated after f(x) is obtained.
One way is numerically.
Other way is algebraically, but I don't know yet how to.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but possibly a start... We may observe, that for $x=0$ the lhs is nonzero, so in the rhs the infinite product is $0 \cdot f(0) \cdot \ldots$ and the $f^{\circ k}(0)$ must account for that zero-cofactor. Now if we have $f(x) = x - \log(x)$ then this is indeed infinite at zero - but this option might be the/one reason for the problem.

If we reformulate the function f(x) such that 
$$ \exp(x) = (x+1) \cdot f^{ \circ 1}(x+1) \cdot \ldots $$ 
then at x=0 we have on the rhs a product of all ones, which is what "we would like" and we could rewrite 
$$ \exp(x-1) = {\exp(x) \over e } = x \cdot f^{ \circ 1}(x) \cdot \ldots $$ 
and get the relation, which we actually find empirically.
However, I think that argument must be made stronger and more formal - as far as my thoughts go it is merely a hint.
[update]: Also, changing the function this way, such that $g(x) = (x+1) + \log(1+x)$ crashes the infinite product, it becomes badly divergent...

Additionally, this reminds me of a similar-looking effect, namely the incomplete gamma function , where the ratio of the incomplete gammas at x and at x+1 behave like the gamma itself, but have an additional constant term -for instance $\frac 1e$-, which is also expressed by some integral. However - this is only a vague feeling of being related in a way, I cannot really formalize ...